# Powershell Console resize: Win 7 vs Win 10

Tags: powershell, console

I have a benchmarking script that resizes the console to 80x4 to show what benchmark test is running, and then resizes to 100x50 to show tabulated final results. It works like a champ on Windows 7/PS2.0, but it refuses to resize on Windows 10/PS 4.0. It doesn't throw any errors, it just doesn't resize. I have checked by my sizes are less than the Max allowed, on both OSs. As far as I can tell there is no way to check for a minimum size. Is there some difference in console behavior in Windows 10 that accounts for this? I CAN manually resize the resulting console, it just won't do it on it's own. It's been rough just getting it to work in Windows 10, so rather disappointing to then have Windows 10 barf on testing. :(

```
function Set-Console {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [switch]$final = $false
    )

    Clear-Host

    $psHost = Get-Host
    if ($final) {
        $height = 50
        $width = 100
    } else {
        $height = 4
        $width = 80
    }
    if (-not ($psHost.ui.rawUi.windowTitle.startsWith('RFO Benchmark'))) {
        $psHost.ui.rawUi.windowTitle = "RFO Benchmark $revitVersion"
        $psHost.ui.rawUi.cursorSize = "50"
        $psHost.ui.rawUi.backgroundColor            = "White"
        $psHost.ui.rawUi.foregroundColor            = "Black"

        $psHost.privatedata.DebugForegroundColor    = "Black"
        $psHost.privatedata.DebugBackgroundColor    = "White"
        $psHost.privatedata.ErrorForegroundColor    = "Red"
        $psHost.privatedata.ErrorBackgroundColor    = "White"
        $psHost.privatedata.ProgressForegroundColor = "Black"
        $psHost.privatedata.ProgressBackgroundColor = "White"
        $psHost.privatedata.VerboseForegroundColor  = "Black"
        $psHost.privatedata.VerboseBackgroundColor  = "White"
        $psHost.privatedata.WarningForegroundColor  = "Black"
        $psHost.privatedata.WarningBackgroundColor  = "White"
    }

    # Set buffer size
    $newSize = $psHost.ui.rawUi.buffersize
    if ($final) {
        $newSize.height = $height * 10
        $newSize.width = $width
    } else {
        $newSize.height = $height
        $newSize.width = $width
    }
    $psHost.ui.rawUi.buffersize = $newSize

    # Set Window size
    $newSize = $psHost.ui.rawUi.windowsize
    $newSize.height = $height
    $newSize.width = $width
    $psHost.ui.rawUi.windowsize = $newSize 

    Clear-Host
}
```

Added detail. This code is used to minimize and restore the console window.

```
function Set-WindowStyle {
    param(
        [Parameter()]
        [ValidateSet('FORCEMINIMIZE', 'HIDE', 'MAXIMIZE', 'MINIMIZE', 'RESTORE', 
                     'SHOW', 'SHOWDEFAULT', 'SHOWMAXIMIZED', 'SHOWMINIMIZED', 
                     'SHOWMINNOACTIVE', 'SHOWNA', 'SHOWNOACTIVATE', 'SHOWNORMAL')]
        $state = 'MINIMIZE',
        [Parameter()]$windowHandle = (Get-Process –id:$pid).mainWindowHandle
    )

    $windowStates = @{
        'FORCEMINIMIZE'   = 11
        'HIDE'            = 0
        'MAXIMIZE'        = 3
        'MINIMIZE'        = 6
        'RESTORE'         = 9
        'SHOW'            = 5
        'SHOWDEFAULT'     = 10
        'SHOWMAXIMIZED'   = 3
        'SHOWMINIMIZED'   = 2
        'SHOWMINNOACTIVE' = 7
        'SHOWNA'          = 8
        'SHOWNOACTIVATE'  = 4
        'SHOWNORMAL'      = 1
    }

    $showWindow = Add-Type –memberDefinition @” 
[DllImport("user32.dll")] 
public static extern bool ShowWindowAsync(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow); 
“@ -name:“Win32ShowWindowAsync” -namespace:Win32Functions –passThru

    $showWindow::ShowWindowAsync($windowHandle, $windowStates[$state]) > $null

}
```

I start my script minimized by shortcut setting. Then I `Set-Console` to the smaller size. As each part of the test runs I `Set-WindowStyle MINIMIZE`, Clear-Host then `Write-Host` the currently running benchmark section. All that works great. Upon completion I `Set-WindowStyle RESTORE`, `Set-Console -final` then `Write-Host` the results from an array. If I put the resort at the end in Windows 7, as I would like to do, then the console resize fails there. But with the Restore at either end in Windows 10 the `Set-Console -final` resize fails.

Comment: Unable to reproduce with PowerShell on Win10. How do you launch `powershell.exe`? What happens if you launch `powershell.exe -noprofile`, paste the `Set-Console` function definition and then invoke `Set-Console`?

Comment: I launch with a shortcut, and I use the noProfile switch. I pulled the function into a little test jig script just now, and unfortunately it works there! So, must be something in the other 900 lines of code causing the issue, but that's the only code that relates to the console, so not sure what it could be.

Comment: One thought, there is another bit of code that manages minimizing and restoring the console. As it works now it resizes the console, writes a bunch of info then restores. Perhaps in Windows 10 I need a different order?

Comment: Could you post the other bit and describe the order in which you invoke it?

Comment: There have definitely been some major changes in how console windows work in Windows 10.   For example, ANSI/VT100 escape sequences are now supported, and there seem to have been bugs caused in some applications/libraries related to the change.

Comment: Burt, thanks for the heads up. At least I feel a little less like I am going nuts.

Comment: The odd thing is, it seems to not be all machines, just some, and I can't pin down what the differences are. Some friends have no issues at all. Curiouser and curiouser.